# Short story about teaching a brontosaurus to fly

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, soft-sci-fi

Read in the UK many (possibly the late 1960s) years ago - I didn't read many magazines so most likely in an anthology.

There's an alien planet inhabited by these dinosaurs who very closely resemble brontosaurus's. There is some reason (I don't recall why) that the big lizards need to be able to take to the skies, they have the dormant and long forgotten ability to levitate but never use it.

Some Earthmen are trying to teach them to start using this power again to help save their species but the humans are so small in comparison that the dinosaur's don't take much notice of them.

One man gets a brainwave and they then use projectors and tractor beams to create a giant human who basically plays with one dinosaur like a large dog, rough and tumble fun and games.
With using this simulation they gradually get the alien reptile to begin using its innate ability and then to pass it on to its fellow dinosaurs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is *[Trouble with Emily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hospital_Station)*, one of the *Sector General* short stories.

> Conway is ordered to assist with a project involving a large dinosaur-like alien, dubbed Emily for its supposed resemblance to Brontosaurus.
>
> [image: Cover of "Hospital Station" by James White. "With a whole galaxy to treat, the staff of Sector General had to be much more than just doctors." the cover shows a large brontosaurus-like creature floating over a marshy lake, eating the leaves of trees as a humanoid figure in yellow looks up at it.]

Comment: Yes, this is it. Conway uses a giant image of himself to play with Emily.

Comment: Cheers! As soon as I saw the name "Emily" I remembered it.

Comment: Took me several seconds to realize how they got "Emily" out of "Brontosaurus" (Emily Brontë)

Comment: @BenHocking Oh, thank you! I was wondering about that.